# Show new added field in journal transaction after released of CA304000 pages in Acumatica ERP

Tags: transactions, customization, acumatica

I have already make some customization code for my project,
I make one new field, and this below is the source code when I make my new customization field :

```
  1. GLTranExtension.cs

      using PX.Data;
      using PX.Objects.GL;
      using PX.Objects.SO;
      using PX.Objects.IN;
      using PX.Objects.AR;

      namespace TEST_SGLI.TEST_SGLI.DAC_Extension
      {
         public class GLTranExtension : PXCacheExtension<GLTran>
         {
            #region
            public abstract class usrJobOrderNbr : IBqlTable
            {
            }
            [PXDBString(15, IsFixed = true, IsUnicode = true)]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Job Order Nbr.")]
            [PXSelector(typeof(Search<JobOrderNbr.jobOrderNbrCD>),
                typeof(JobOrderNbr.jobOrderNbrCD),
                typeof(JobOrderNbr.customerID),
                typeof(JobOrderNbr.status))]
            public string UsrJobOrderNbr { get; set; }
            #endregion
         }
     }


  2. CASplitExtension.cs :

     using PX.Data;
     using PX.Objects.CA;
     using PX.Objects.GL;

     namespace TEST_SGLI.TEST_SGLI.DAC_Extension
     {
        public class CASplitExtension : PXCacheExtension<CASplit>
        {
           #region
           public abstract class usrJobOrderNbr : IBqlTable
           {
           }
           [PXDBString(15, IsFixed = true, IsUnicode = true)]
           [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Job Order Nbr.")]
           [PXSelector(typeof(Search<JobOrderNbr.jobOrderNbrCD>),
                typeof(JobOrderNbr.jobOrderNbrCD),
                typeof(JobOrderNbr.customerID),
                typeof(JobOrderNbr.status))]
           public string UsrJobOrderNbr { get; set; }
           #endregion
        }
   }


3. CATranEntryExtension.cs :

   using PX.Data;
   using System.Collections;
   using PX.Objects.CA;
   using PX.Objects.GL;
   using PX.Objects.SO;

   namespace TEST_SGLI.TEST_SGLI.BLC
   {

      public class CATranEntryExtension : PXGraphExtension<CATranEntry>
      {

          public PXAction<CAAdj> action;
          [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Actions", 
               MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Insert,
          MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Insert)]
          [PXProcessButton]

          public IEnumerable Action(PXAdapter adapter,
            [PXIntList(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 },
               new string[]
               {
                   "Approve",
                   "Reject",
                   "Release"
               }), PXInt] int? actionID, [PXString] string actionName)
         {
            if (actionID == 3)
            {
               PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<CATranEntry>((graph) =>
               {
                   graph.RowInserting.AddHandler<GLTran>((sender, e) =>
                   {
                       CASplit csplit = PXResult<CASplit>.Current;

                       DAC_Extension.CASplitExtension splitX = PXCache<CASplit>.GetExtension<DAC_Extension.CASplitExtension>(csplit);

                       if (csplit != null && splitX.UsrJobOrderNbr != null)
                       {
                           DAC_Extension.GLTranExtension glExt = PXCache<GLTran>.GetExtension<DAC_Extension.GLTranExtension>((GLTran)e.Row);
                           glExt.UsrJobOrderNbr = splitX.UsrJobOrderNbr;
                       }
                   }
                );
            });
        }

        return Base.action.Press(adapter);
      }
    }
  }
```

And the scenario is like this picture below :
I make one transaction in Transaction page (CA304000)

After I insert all data for this transaction, and I insert Job Order Nbr = "JO003", and then I click button "Actions", and I choose "Release", all data transactions will be released and show in journal Transaction.

But I job order nbr cannot be inserted into Journal Transaction.

anyone please help me to solve this problem..

Comment: what error you gets with above code?

Comment: Why cant you add a row inserting handler directly in the extension and set your value if the conditions matches.

Comment: There isn't error with above code, but Job Order Nbr cannot inserted in Journal Transaction after released. Sorry, what do you mean about add a row inserting handler directly in the extension and set value if the conditions matches ? if you don't mind, could you write in code please ?

Comment: From the code written above, what i can see is you are adding a row inserting handler while the release button is pressed and you are calling the base method. Can you try adding that handler directly to the graph extension and try to debug your scenario?